# Which folders/files must be copied to the shared hosting server when you want to deploy a Per-Project Homestead Laravel 5.5 application

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, vagrant, homestead

I want to deploy my Laravel project which has a Per-project Homestead inside it (not the global homestead). Some Vagrant and all Homestead files are included inside my Laravel project. This is the first time I'm deploying a Laravel application, and I really cannot find any information about files and folders that may be excluded from the deployment (Especially for a project with a per-project Homestead inside it).

I guess, .vagrant, tests, .env.example, .gitattributes, .gitignore, after.sh, aliases, Homestead.yaml, phpunit.xml, readme.md, and Vagrantfile files and folders may be excluded. Am I right? And what about the vendor folder (There are some Vagrant, Homestead files inside, as well, like e.g. homestead, homestead.bat inside the vendor/bin folder, or the whole homestead folder inside vendor/laravel).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would use a VPS or deployment server like DigitalOcean.  However, as you stated you are using a shared server, the directories/files you will need to upload **to the `root` directory** of your server account are:

```
app/*
bootstrap/*
config/*
database/*
public_html/*
resources/*
routes/*
storage/*
vendor/*
.env
```

The remaining .files are for dependency management and development tests, and since you likely won't be using any build processes or Continuous Integration on a shared server, you won't need them.

**Note:** make sure these are in the root directory and the only publicly accessible directory is `public_html`. By default, shared hosting servers already have this restriction. Uploading the Laravel project as you have it will overwrite the website's current `public_html` directory, so make sure to back up anything you may have there currently.

#### Update

Frameworks like Laravel are designed to use root/command-line access to assist with deployment and server management. This is the advantage of frameworks. Shared servers do not typically allow users root access, so you end up having issues like yours, where deployment is a manual upload instead of a CLI command through version control.

`vendor` contains all of the dependencies your app is relying on to operate (Eloquent, Doctrine, Flysystem, etc.), so it won't work without the `vendor` directory.

Comment: Concerning public_html; I've changed the name of this folder myself with the appropriate settings and links to this folder inside my laravel-app, because there was no public folder on the server.

Comment: And concerning the "vendor" folder. The whole Homestead is is cloned inside this folder. It's not that much in kilobytes, but it's still redundant, isnt it?

Comment: And finally, although a VPS is a quite pretty "thing", it costs too much money, and it's a matter of choice (concerning this issue).

Comment: @LowLevel Why did you downvote my answer? What part of it didn't answer your question? I didn't say "don't use a shared server", I just said that you would _ideally_ be using a service like DigitalOcean or even Laravel Forge for hosting and deployment.

Comment: Some people are having fun downvoting on stackoverflow. My question is downvoted as well.

Comment: @LowLevel Gotcha. Well, in that case, did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: I think they didn't have enough rights in their lives. Now they have the right to down-vote, and they just feel lucky doing it. Like Einstein said about infinity of stupidity and the universe: "never mind".

Comment: I didn't have a problem. I first must try it out. I'm currently solving another issue which has higher priority. I've found out that the server, on which I deploy my Laravel-app, supports PHP 7.0.28, while my Laravel-app version is 5.5, which requires at least PHP 7.1.3. So, I'm now downgrading my Laravel-app version, and replacing the app on the server, first. And it takes so much time because of that much megabytes.

Comment: After it's done, I'll remove the (possibly) redundant files and folders one-by-one and check every time what happens. When I'm sure your answer is correct, I'll check it (I'm not sure it will be today; first my current problem must be solved), so if someone looks for a solution on web for this issue, he does not take wrong actions.

Comment: correction: it was Laravel 5.6. I've downgraded to 5.4. I could downgrade to 5.5, as 5.5 supports php >= 7.0.0. So I have one more step to do.

Comment: @LowLevel Were you able to resolve the version issues?

Answer (score 0):

You should deploy from version control, and by default that should exclude `.vagrant` and `Homestead.yaml` everything else is safe to leave in.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you exactly mean. I didn't use any version control system. If you're talking about Git, for example, all the git files are created by default, and I didn't use any Git-thing. Do you mean a kind-of sync using git?

Comment: You should be using version control (even if you're the only developer on a project). You should do some research on http://www.phptherightway.com/ specifically around http://www.phptherightway.com/#servers_and_deployment